# Can't make POST request - AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm pretty new to Xcode, and I'm trying to make a POST request. I searched on Google and found this AFNetworking library. I've read some documentation but they all say different things. So now I use their own example on a POST request and my code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"fName": @"firstname", @"lName": @"lastname"};
    [manager POST:@"http://00000.1111.ovh/api/Account/register" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

And then I get this error:

> Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response
>   Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://00000.1111.ovh/api/Account/register } {
>   status code: 400, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 159;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 15 Nov 2015 12:11:57 GMT";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://00000.1111.ovh/api/Account/register,
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226d65 73736167
>   65223a22 54686520 72657175 65737420 69732069 6e76616c 69642e22
>   2c226d6f 64656c53 74617465 223a7b22 6c6f6769 6e2e7573 65726e61
>   6d65223a 5b225468 65205573 6572206e 616d6520 6669656c 64206973
>   20726571 75697265 642e225d 2c226c6f 67696e2e 70617373 776f7264
>   223a5b22 54686520 50617373 776f7264 20666965 6c642069 73207265
>   71756972 65642e22 5d7d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad
>   request (400)}

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and dont use this Framework.  use NSURLSession instead.

Comment: Claus, I'd hesitate to advise against using this framework. For new users, properly encoding requests is very complicated (e.g. 99% of the examples I see here online fail to percent-escape requests properly). Sure, if you don't like the fact that `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is `NSURLConnection` based (which is now deprecated), then use the very similar `AFHTTPSessionManager` (which is `NSURLSession` based).

Comment: @Claus: though AFNetworking might be an overkill in some (especially simple) cases you are giving an "i don't get your question but i am willing to answer it anyway" advice here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better diagnose these issues if you translate the server's response into something you can parse/examine:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"fName": @"firstname", @"lName": @"lastname"};
[manager POST:@"http://00000.1111.ovh/api/Account/register" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    if (operation.responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", operation.responseObject);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"responseString = %@", operation.responseString);
    }
}];
```

If you did that, you'd see that it responded with:

```
responseObject = {
    message = "The request is invalid.";
    modelState =     {
        "login.password" =         (
            "The Password field is required."
        );
        "login.username" =         (
            "The User name field is required."
        );
    };
}
```

Apparently, the request was missing the necessary authentication details.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpfull!!

Answer (score 1):

Your request is sent correctly, but the server responded with HTTP code 400. Check the server's API documentation on how the request should look like.